# NIFI: NoClassDefFoundError - AbstractListProcessor

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I'm extending a standard processor to create a custom nifi processor. The project builds fine. But, when I restart my nifi after adding the newly generated nar to lib/ directory, nifi fails to start with `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```java
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nifi/processor/util/list/AbstractListProcessor
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.loadExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:138)
        at org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.discoverExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:113)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:699)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:160)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:267)
```

Can someone help me understand if I'm missing something here.

I'm using the following dependencies in processor-bundle's `POM.xml`:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-standard-processors</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-processor-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My imports in my code:

```java
    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    import org.apache.nifi.components.PropertyDescriptor;
    import org.apache.nifi.flowfile.attributes.CoreAttributes;
    import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessContext;
    import org.apache.nifi.processor.util.StandardValidators;
    import org.apache.nifi.processor.util.list.AbstractListProcessor;
    import org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.FileInfo;
    import org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.FileTransfer;
    import org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally processors aren't really meant to be extended and it would be better to not have a dependency on nifi-standard-nar. The nifi-processor-utils project exists to hold common code to share across processors like AbstractListProcessor:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-extension-utils

If there is other code in nifi-standard-processors that should be shared then we should look at refactoring and moving it into modules under nifi-extension-utils.

For now, you are probably better off copying and pasting ListFile, FileTransfer, and FileInfo into your own project and modifying them accordingly, and remove the dependency on nifi-standard-processors.

To answer the specific question about why you get that exception... its because your NAR needs to have a NAR dependency on nifi-standard-nar in order to resolve the classes at runtime. This wiki page shows an example which would be the same situation:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Maven+Projects+for+Extensions#MavenProjectsforExtensions-LinkingProcessorsandControllerServices

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Bryan. Moving the files to my project and adding nar dependency on nifi-standard-nar did the trick.

Comment: No problem. Just to clarify, you probably only want to do one of those things, meaning move the files to your project so you don't need to depend on standard nar, or depend on standard nar and don't move the files. If you do both it might still work, but technically you will have two copies of ListFile on the classpath then.

Answer (score 1):

check that in your nar (nifi archive) the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`
contains `Nar-*` attributes

for example this one defines dependency on another nar:

```
Nar-Dependency-Id: nifi-standard-services-api-nar
```

and libraries from `nifi-standard-services-api-nar.nar` will be available in classloader of your nar file...

read this:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#nars